# spring message tag with multiple arguments

Tags: java, spring, jsp, jstl

I am trying to get i18n message like below:

messageCode=Test message for {0} and {1} and {2}.

In jsp, I have this:

```
<spring:message code="messageCode" 
                arguments="${value1},${value2},${value3}" 
                htmlEscape="false"/>
```

The arguments:

```
value1=A,B
value2=C,D
value3=E,F
```

The output for what I want:

```
Test message for A,B and C,D and E,F
```

The actual output:

```
Test message for A and B and C
```

Is there any way to overcome this? Thank you.

George

Answer (score 67, accepted):

*The cause of the probelm is that `,` (comma) is the default separator. So at the end the spring message tag will get the String `A,B,C,D,E,F` for parameter `arguments`, and it will split this string into 6 different internal arguments for the message.*

You  must change the separator. If you use `;` for example, then it will work.

```
<spring:message code="messageCode"
       arguments="${value1};${value2};${value3}"
       htmlEscape="false"
       argumentSeparator=";"/>
```

@See [Spring Reference: Appendix F.6 The Message Tag](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/spring.tld.html#spring.tld.message)

Comment: adding ` htmlEscape="false"
       argumentSeparator=";"` solved my problem

Answer (score 2):

You could also send the different values as an array and leave no room for spring making a mistake in how to parse the string argument.

```
<c:set var="value1" value="A,B;X" />
<c:set var="value2" value="C,D;Y" />
<c:set var="value3" value="E,F;Z" />

<spring:message code="messageCode"
   arguments="${[value1, value2, value3]}"
   htmlEscape="false" />
```

This way you need no worry about your new separator somehow being used in a value at some point again.

Answer (score 1):

I use completely different approach. My database-based message source is exposed in my config with the name i18n:

```
@Bean(name = {"i18n", "messageSource"})
public MessageSource messageSource() {
    return new JpaMessageSource();
}
```

and I also expose my beans with `viewResolver.setExposeContextBeansAsAttributes(true);`
After that I can use `${i18n.message("messageCode", value1, value2, value3)}` in my jsp-views.